# Almost periodicity and approximation in tracial von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, approximation-theory

Let $N$ be a von Neumann algebra with a faithful normal tracial state $\tau$. For a countable group $G$, let $\sigma: G\rightarrow \text{Aut}(N)$ be a $G$- action on $N$ which preserves the tracial state $\tau$ (i.e. $\sigma_g(nm)=\sigma_g(n)\cdot\sigma_g(m)$ and $\tau(\sigma_g(n))=\tau(n)$ for $n,\,m\in N$ and for $g\in G$).

**Problem:** Let $m,n\in N$. For each $g\in G$, let there exists $k_g\in N$ so that we have $\sup_{g\in G}\|\sigma_g(m)-k_g\cdot n\|_2<1$. Then, for each $g\in G$, can we find $k_g'$ in the von Neumann algebra generated by $k_g$ so that $\|\sigma_g(m)-k_g'\cdot n\|_2<1$ holds where $\{k_g':g\in G\}$ satisfies $\sup_g\|k_g'\|<\infty$?

Note that the $L^2$- norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ on $N$ is defined by $\|n\|_2=\tau(nn^*)^{1/2},\,n\in N$.
I was trying to prove that we can choose $k_g'=k_g\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[-K,K]}(k_g) $, and for some sufficiently large $K$, these $k_g'$'s should work, though I did not get it. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

P.S. I asked this question in [https://math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370015/almost-periodicity-and-approximation-in-tracial-von-neumann-algebra) but didn't get any help.

Comment: Yes. Let $a$ and $b$ be given in a tracial von Neumann algebra. Put $C:=\|a\|$. Then $x_n:=a1_{[1/n,\|b\|]}(|b|)|b|^{-2}b^*$ satisfies $\|x_n\|\le Cn$, 
\begin{align*}
\| a-x_nb\|_2 &= \|a 1_{[0,1/n)}(|b|)\|_2\\ 
 &\to \|a 1_{\{0\}}(|b|)\|_2=\inf_{x\in M} \| a-xb\|_2,
\end{align*} 
and 
\begin{align*}
\| a-x_nb\|_2^2 -\inf_{x\in M} \| a-xb\|_2 &= \|a 1_{(0,1/n)}(|b|)\|_2^2\\
 &\le C^2\| 1_{(0,1/n)}(|b|)\|_2^2 \to 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thanks. Actually, for each $g\in G$ I wanted to get $k_g'$ in the von Neumann subalgebra generated by $k_g$ (Sorry to skip that part in question. Now it's edited accordingly). Please let me know if that can be done. Also, in your comment, how to get $\|a\mathbb{1}_{\{0\}}(|b|)\|_2=\inf_{x\in N}\|a-xb\|_2$?

Comment: Well, that's not true even for $2$-by-$2$ matrix algebra $N$ and the trivial action of an infinite group.

Comment: Could you please provide such elements $a,b,k_g,\,g\in G$ explicitly with a details argument of why can't I find any such $k_g'$?